# umount of sdcard leaves fat-fs unclean

Tags: linux, usb-drive, unmounting

**When I umount a SD flash card in a USB card reader, and then pull the card, filesystem stays "dirty".**

System:

- RPi or xubuntu 16.04.3
- The card reader is some super cheap Chinese one. I have tried a few different ones
- I have tried a bunch of different SD cards.

How to reproduce:

1. connect card reader
2. insert SD card with vfat on the first partition
3. wait for system to detect SD card
4. wait for system to automount filesystem or mount it manually
5. update a random file, I do: `date >> /media/mogul/2E3E-AE54/d`
6. un-mount: `sudo umount /dev/sdd1`
7. (placeholder, do nothing here, yet)
8. pull sd card from card reader

Now repeat from step 2. Keep an eye on your dmesg, it will say:

`[357207.805594] FAT-fs (sdd1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.`

*(newer linux's support `dmesg -w`)*

Now, if I add an additional action after the `umount`

7. read a random byte on the SD card, like: `dd if=/dev/sdd1 skip=1000000 ibs=1 count=1 of=/dev/null`

the filesystem seems to survive.

**This seems a bit hackish to me, am I missing something fundamental?**

**Do you have more elegant solutions?**

I prefer not to use `eject`, but only `umount, since`eject` powers down the card reader too; the system won’t detect a new SD card before I re-plug the card reader.

Comment: Currently I'm using `fdisk -l /dev/sdd`, look a little less odd in the surrounding program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your step 7, try the following:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/block/sdd/device/delete
```

or if you're running as root, just

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdd/device/delete
```

This signals the kernel that device `/dev/sdd` is about to be removed, and should trigger a controlled flushing of any remaining write buffers to the card, to avoid the filesystem corruption.

This may cause the reader to power down similar to the the `eject` command; if it does, an alternative way would be to just flush the buffers without the implication of an imminent device removal. This can be achieved with the `blockdev` command:

```
sudo blockdev --flushbufs /dev/sdd
```

If this does not help, then I'm afraid the card reader might not support hot-unplugging the card. This is possible with cheap readers. The only safe way to use such a reader could then be to first unplug the reader from the USB port, and only then remove the card from the reader.

Comment: As "expected" signalling `delete` to the kernel did the same as `eject`, removing `/dev/sdd`. The `blockdev --flushbufs` did not fix the problem either.

Comment: Then it appears the card reader cannot handle hot-unplugging the card at all. Added that to my answer.

Comment: And you are correct. Apparently my collection of card readers was too cheap. Tried a few built-in ones in laptops, they all performed much better. No need for weird reads after the `umount`

Answer (score 0):

Issuing the command `sync` at step 7 will write the buffer cache to the SD card and will result in a clean file system.

Comment: nope, `sync` was one of my first attempts. didn't work